# MS Word number of pages in a flextable table using Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, flextable, officer, officedown

Is there a way to insert MS Word computed field - total number of pages in the document - into a flextable table?

In the `officer` package there's a function `run_word_field`. I tried to use it the following way:

```
flextable(df) %>%
  compose(value = as_paragraph(
    as_chunk(run_word_field(field = "NumPages  \\* MERGEFORMAT"))
  ))
```

but it throws an error.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: I've created an issue for this to come in flextable, https://github.com/davidgohel/flextable/issues/404, 404 for a missing feature, isn't it funny?

Comment: Great, I'll be looking forward to this feature. 404 is a really funny coincidence here :)

Comment: @DavidGohel, I registered an issue on GitHub. It seems there's something wrong with "\n" interpretation in the new version.

Comment: yes, there is an ongoing work on tabs and newlines. Why do you relate this to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can now use function `as_word_field`:

```
library(flextable)
library(officer)

# define some default values ----
set_flextable_defaults(font.size = 22, border.color = "gray")

ft_2 <- flextable(head(cars))
ft_2 <- add_footer_lines(ft_2, "temp text")
ft_2 <- compose(
  x = ft_2, part = "footer", i = 1, j = 1, 
  as_paragraph("p. ", 
               as_word_field(x = "Page"),
               " on ", as_word_field(x = "NumPages"))
)
ft_2 <- autofit(ft_2, part = c("header", "body"))

doc <- read_docx() 
doc <- body_add_flextable(doc, ft_2) 
doc <- body_add_break(doc) 
doc <- body_add_flextable(doc, ft_2) 
outfile <- print(doc, target = tempfile(fileext = ".docx"))
```

[image]